# Error with editin categories in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a database with table categories. I create a functionality to add delete read and edit categories. But reading adding and deleting works fine but editing shows an error.

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include "includes/admin_navigation.php"?>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">
                        Blank Page
                        <small>Subheading</small>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <?php // add category

                        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                            $cat_name = $_POST['cat_name'];

                            if ($cat_name == "" || empty($cat_name)) {
                                echo "this field should not be empty";
                            } else {
                                $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_name) VALUE('$cat_name')";

                                $create_category = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                                if(!$create_category){
                                    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
                        <form action="categories.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cat_name">Enter category name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cat_name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="btn primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add category">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <form action="categories.php" method="post">

                            <?php // edit category


                            if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
                                $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = {$cat_id}";

                                $select_categories_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_id)){

                                $cat_title = $row['cat_name'];
                                $the_cat_id = $row['id']; ?>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cat_name">Edit category name</label>
                                    <input value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)) {echo $cat_title;} ?>" class="form-control" type="text" name="cat_name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="btn primary" type="submit" name="update_category" value="Edit category">
                                </div>
                            <?php }

                            }

                            if (isset($_POST['update_category'])) {
                                $update_cat_title = $_POST['cat_name'];
                                $query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_name = {$update_cat_title} WHERE id = {$cat_id}"; // the problem is with  $cat_id (on videolesson everything works fine but on my local pc becomes next error - Notice: Undefined variable: the_cat_id in /var/www/html/wordpress/cms/CMS_TEMPLATE/admin/categories.php on line 75)
                                $update_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                                if(!$update_query){

                                    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));

                                }
                            }

                            ?>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th colspan="3">CATEGORY TITLE</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            <?php  // delete category

                            $query = "SELECT * FROM categories"; // find categories query
                            $select_categories_sidebar = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_sidebar)){

                                $cat_title = $row['cat_name'];
                                $cat_id = $row['id'];

                                echo "

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        {$cat_id}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {$cat_title}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='categories.php?edit={$cat_id}'>Edit</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='categories.php?delete={$cat_id}'>Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                ";
                            }

                            if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
                                $del_cat_id = $_GET['delete'];

                                $query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = {$del_cat_id} "; // delete category
                                $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                                header("location: categories.php");
                            }

                            ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not parsing the `cat_id` through to the `update_category` POST request.

Change your edit FORM code to this:

```
<form action="categories.php" method="post">

    <?php // edit category


    if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
        $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = {$cat_id}";

        $select_categories_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_id)){

        $cat_title = $row['cat_name'];
        $the_cat_id = $row['id']; ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cat_name">Edit category name</label>
            <input value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)) {echo $cat_title;} ?>" class="form-control" type="text" name="cat_name">
            <input value="<?php if(isset($the_cat_id)) {echo $the_cat_id;} ?>" name="cat_id" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn primary" type="submit" name="update_category" value="Edit category">
        </div>
    <?php }

    }

    if (isset($_POST['update_category'])) {
        $update_cat_title = $_POST['cat_name'];
        $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
       $query = "UPDATE categories SET `cat_name` = '{$update_cat_title}' WHERE `id` = '{$cat_id}' LIMIT 1"; // the problem is with  $cat_id (on videolesson everything works fine but on my local pc becomes next error - Notice: Undefined variable: the_cat_id in /var/www/html/wordpress/cms/CMS_TEMPLATE/admin/categories.php on line 75)

        $update_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$update_query){

            die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));

        }
    }

    ?>


</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I will try to remake from the beginning. Maybe I have lost something.

Comment: Worked perfectly on my side. Are you sure you incorporated all the changes I added?

Comment: It works, but I getting the $cat_id, not from the post. I have another button that takes id from the table of categories using GET. I create an if statement that checks is the edit button clicked and load the form to edit the specific category. On the video, the teacher does the same and it works. But I can't do that... The there is no errors now from php or mysql. I really don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: The form is don't want to post values using a get parameter. To send values I had to insert get parameter directly in the form action, like this: 

<form action="categories.php?edit=<?php echo $up_cat_id;?>" method="post"><!-- edit form -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_title">Update category</label>